# How to update Wordpress ajaxurl variable to use SSL?

Tags: ajax, wordpress, ssl, https, wordpress-4.0

We run a Wordpress 4.0/Buddypress setup and ever since we switched to SSL all ajax functions are not working because the ajaxurl variable is still reading "http".

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 /* <![CDATA[ */
 var ajaxurl = 'http://website.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php';
 /* ]]> */
</script>
```

This code is added to wp_head automatically so we're not really sure how to update it. We just need to switch http to https.

Does anyone know how we can do this?

**We get this error each time ajax is required:** *[blocked] The page at 'https://website.com/users' was loaded over HTTPS, but ran insecure content from 'http://website.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php': this content should also be loaded over HTTPS.*

Comment: Anyone have any advice on this?

Answer (score 3):

The `ajaxurl` variable gets its value from the [admin_url()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/admin_url) function, which in turn figures out whether or not to do `https` based on the result of the [is_ssl()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_ssl) function.

So, basically, if you're not getting `https` in your `ajaxurl`, the `is_ssl()` function isn't properly detecting SSL on your site.

If you're behind a load balancer or reverse proxy that supports `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO` (like ELB), add the following to `wp-config.php`, per the documentation:

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https')
     $_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';
```

If that doesn't work, take a look at the `gist` that's linked in [the Notes section](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_ssl#Notes) for the `is_ssl()` documentation. You should add that to your plugins directory.

Answer (score 2):

I also have this problem with Wordpress, particularly because I use CloudFlare Flexible SSL.

I did this quick and dirty patch on /wp-includes/load.php

```
function is_ssl() {
        if ( isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_CF_VISITOR'] ) ) {
            if ( strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_CF_VISITOR'], "https") !== "false" ){
                return true;
            }
        }

        if ( isset( $_SERVER['HTTPS'] ) ) {
                if ( 'on' == strtolower( $_SERVER['HTTPS'] ) ) {
                        return true;
                }

                if ( '1' == $_SERVER['HTTPS'] ) {
                        return true;
                }
        } elseif ( isset($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] ) && ( '443' == $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] ) ) {
                return true;
        }
        return false;
}
```

This helped with the ajax calls from the admin that were blocking lots of plugins' functionality.